# WPF MVVM TextBox не обновляется при изменении свойства Text

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox

В окне есть 2 `UserControl`. В одном есть `ListBox` и при выборе элемента в нем, во втором `UserControl` должен обновляться текст в `TextBox`. Пробовал менять `UpdateSourceTrigger` и `Mode` в `TextBox`. При ручном вводе все обновляется, а при установке значения программой, `get` в поле `CurrentTitle` не вызывается

**View**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentTitle, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public string CurrentTitle
{
    get { return _currentTitle; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentTitle != value)
        {
            _currentTitle = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTitle");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View окна с ListBox**

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentIndex}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNotes}">
```

**ViewModel окна с ListBox**

```
public int CurrentIndex
{
    get { return _currentIndex; }
    set
    {
        _currentIndex = value;
        SetCurrentValues();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentIndex");
    }
}

private void SetCurrentValues()
{
    CurrentTitle = ListOfNotes[CurrentIndex].Title;
}
```

`Title` - поле из `Model`

Comment: У вас окно одно, а ViewModel две?

Comment: у меня на окно и на UserControl`ы по ViewModel

Comment: Судя по коду, у вас свойство CurrentTitle и метод SetCurrentValues находятся в разных VM, соответственно разные VM должны друг с другом как-то общаться. Могу предположить, что у вас созданы  разные экземпляры классов VM, поэтому вы не видите изменений. Нужно использовать единый экземпляр VM.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. У меня эти 2 ViewModel от UserContol`ов наследуют ViewModelBase куда я и вынес CurrentTitle и интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, не знаю насколько это правильно, я надеялся что так заработает, но не заработало. Я посмотрел что CurrentTitle принимает значение, но TextBox после этого ничего не запрашивает

Comment: Стоп. Не так все делается.  ViewModelBase должна реализовывать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged и максимум там может быть метод, который используется в set-теарх  свойств классов потомков. Собственно в этом методе код который у вас выглядит так:  if (_currentTitle != value)
        {
            _currentTitle = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTitle");
        }

Comment: Если вы устанавливаете DataContext для окна - VM окна. И DataContext для UserControl - VM UC, то чтобы выбраться из контекста UC в контекст окна - нужно в привязке использовать RelativeSource. Во ViewModelBase не нужно добавлять свойства и поля.

Comment: Сделал все как вы сказали и заработало! Дело было в том, что поля находились в VM UC, а не VM окна.  Огромное вам спасибо за помощь. Пойду штудировать теорию